# How to make a request for sending a list of rows in a rest client -Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, json, rest

I am working on a REST client in android.My web service is based on Rails.My scenario is that I have an class  named *user* which has attributes like *age*,name,*gender* etc.I want to send a list of user objects to the server so that i can insert it into the database.Can someone let me know how i can do this using json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your user class be a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and then post the objects to your server as JSON strings using `JSONObject.quote()` and turn those strings back into arrays/objects at the server end.

Comment: Hi Ben.I have used the gson library to convert the objects to a json array.Thanks for the info on json.